# URL Redirect with masking

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, redirect, url-masking

I am currently facing a problem to redirect a URL.
What I want is that I have a subdomain files.mrblade.info.
Now I want to forward this domain to someurl.com but with masking i.e I don't want to show someurl.com I would like to show files.mrblade.info in the addressbar.
Also I want that if I enter a URL like file.mrblade.info/1.jpg then the link that it should forward to should be someurl.com/1.jpg but again the url should be masked and should show files.mrblade.info/1.jpg in addressbar.

I came across 2 solutions using different forums and google but none worked perfectly for me.
The 2 solutions are:

1. Htacess

   ```
   rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} ^files.mrblade.info$ 
   rewriterule ^filesdir\/(.*)$ "https\:\/\/googledrive.com\/host\/0B- qKiTeWoeqgdzRSLWlIQWloVWc\/$1" [R=301,L] #538842ee1488f
   ```

   Using htaccess, the redirection is working properly like if I enter url like files.mrblade.info/1.jpg it open the correct file but masking is not available.
   After redirection the final redirected url is shown, i dont want that :\
2. HTML Frameset

   ```
   <FRAMESET border=0 rows="100%,*" frameborder="no" marginleft=0 margintop=0 marginright=0 marginbottom=0> 
   <frame src="https://googledrive.com/host/0B-qKiTeWoeqgdzRSLWlIQWloVWc/" scrolling=auto frameborder="no" border=0 noresize> 
   <frame topmargin="0" marginwidth=0 scrolling=no marginheight=0 frameborder="no" border=0 noresize> 
   </FRAMESET>
   ```

   using frameset the redirect is done with masking but if i enter files.mrblade.info/1.jpg it will not open the file like htaccess method, it will just open the final url but masked.

Please help me, I want to redirect with masking also if i enter a value like `files.mrblade.info/1.jpg` then it should open

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to configure your webserver (Apache if I get it right) to serve certain urls as **reverse proxy**. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html